# What are the performance characteristics of sending big messages in Distributed Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Suppose I create new local process in an Erlang application, and i want to send to it a big message.

```
-module(chain_hello). 

start(N, Some_big_data)->                                    
   Pid1 = spawn(chain_hello, some_fun, [N]),
   Pid1 ! Some_big_data,
   io:format("done \n").
```

despite `Some_big_data` is a reference to really big data (eg. content of a file) - is it copied when sending? Are there big penalties for performance?

Normally I would use some thread safe shared object (and/or mutex). Is there any solution in Erlang to avoid copying message content?

**ADDED:** 
 Interesting case is when Some_big_data is structured content - to be specific: map, on which I can perform some operations.

**ADDED2** 
 Ok, I see there is no such solution for Erlang (sharing  some structured data like map in worker process) - because of Erlang design. But I think it is justified by solid work, and easily concurrence management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a suggestion, you can send only the pid of the current process (self()) to the process that you want to handle that some_big_data. That way, when you want to use that some_big_data, you can reference it back to it from the 2nd process.

For instance:

```
-module(proc1).

send_big_data() ->
  BigData = get_some_big_data(),
  Pid = spawn(fun proc2:start/0),
  Pid ! {process_big_data, self()},
  loop(Pid, BigData).

loop(Pid,BigData) ->
  receive
    get_first_element ->
      [H|T] = BigData,
      Pid ! {response, H};
    _ ->
      Pid ! {nothing}
   end,
   loop(Pid).
```

(Sorry for the eventual syntax mistakes).

Comment: I suppose this is only "erlangish solution" (which sounds quiet well, but not efficient) - call and copy the value by need through separate data manager process. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 6):

From the [Erlang Efficiency Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#id66069):

> All data in messages between Erlang
>   processes is copied, with the
>   exception of [refc binaries](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#refc_binary) on the same
>   Erlang node.

Yes, you should avoid sending big terms between processes. If you need to send a lot of data, send it as a binary.

Comment: Well, of course you can send pieces of structured data separately, but I didn't see that as "big data". That is many pieces of "small data", in my opinion. With the knowledge that terms are being copied, one can structure the program to achieve the least amount of copying. Note however, that copying small pieces one at a time will still copy the same amount of data, just in another fashion (which of course might be faster in a particular case. Benchmark!).

Comment: yes - but if you need to take benefits from structured data composed in refc Binary you need to make a copy.
Beside this binaries are good for common data (sequences, strings, documents etc..)

Comment: In fact, sub binaries pattern matched from bigger binaries are only references back into the big binary: see [binary:referenced_byte_size/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#referenced_byte_size-1). Binaries *are* the most efficient way of sending data to another process in Erlang, all else will be copied.