# Sending big lists between processes in Erlang / Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, message-passing

Suppose you want to send a big list (1_000_000 entries for example) to a different process in Erlang / Elixir.

- Does `send` block until the data of the whole list is sent, or is that somehow done asynchronously by the Erlang VM?
- Is simply sending the list a bad practice? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Dont think it's a good idea. Check this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394566/erlang-sending-big-message-performance

Comment: You could possibly use [ets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) to store your data in and pass references to the table(s) around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes and no. Copying of huge structure doesn't block receiver but sender. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30711290/49197) to a similar question.
- Yes, it is bad practice if you do it regularly. Alternatively:

  1. Refactor your code so you could partition data to different processes.
  2. Store data in `ets`. (It's not a magic bullet, you still copy data in and out of `ets` but it depends on your access pattern.)
  3. Store data as binary.

It depends on what do you do. You should not have a big heap in a process so probably you should refactor your code.

Comment: I was just asking out of curiosity, as i am currently faced with communicating a big list of data between two threads in Java. Concurrency in Java is a real pain, so i was interested in how i would do the same thing in Elixir which uses message passing. If i had to solve the same thing in Elixir i would probably use an ets table or a separate process that provides a list-like access pattern, like you said.

Comment: @LucaFülbier: Keep in mind that even you will use proxy process with list-like API you still could face long GC pauses due big heap size. Generation nature of Erlang's GC would help but from time to time you would see a long pause in this process response similar to Java behavior.